# How to fix "Consider checking `mounted`." error?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I've read this [issue](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/496), but I've tried all the solutions provided by users and still can't fix this error.

Here is my code:

```dart
await controller.submit(
  …
);
```

```dart
Future<void> createBroadcast(…) async {
 state = state.copyWith(value: const AsyncValue.loading());
  final value = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
    …

    return await …;
  });
  state = state.copyWith(value: value);
}
```

Here is the error:

```
I/flutter ( 1242): Bad state: Tried to use CreateBroadcastScreenController after `dispose` was called.
I/flutter ( 1242):
I/flutter ( 1242): Consider checking `mounted`.
I/flutter ( 1242): …
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Please provide more details - what are you trying to do & when does this error appear?

Comment: @RaviSinghLodhi what kind of information do you need?

Comment: Please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & at least provide information about what you were trying to do. When does this error appear? Add code that makes it easier to understand. Without understanding your problem, it will be really difficult for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the github thread: https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/496#issuecomment-1440144553

Please use mounted check to see if the page want to fetch data for is still on screen or not

```dart
if (mounted) {...}
```

Comment: Hi, where to put `mounted`? Do you put it before `controller.submit` or inside the `submit` function?

Comment: It's not very clear from the code snippet you shared but most likely it'd be before `controller.submit`

Comment: I tried this but still get the same error

Comment: Cannot help you beyond what you've shared. Would need more info.

Comment: What kind of information do you need?

Comment: code + stacktrace, especially the parts where you have used Navigators

Comment: I edited my question but I'm not using Navigators